# how to access image from a dataset using skimage? Is there any other alternate?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scikit-image

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import skimage
train_data_directory = "F:/Projects/Tensorflow/Code/Training"
directories = [d for d in os.listdir(train_data_directory)
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(train_data_directory, d))]
labels =[] 
images = []
for d in directories:
    label_directory = os.path.join(train_data_directory, d)
    file_name = [os.path.join(train_data_directory, f)
                for f in os.listdir(label_directory)
                if f.endswith(".ppm")]
    labels.append(int(d))

for i in file_name:
    skimage.io.imread(i)
```

this is my code, skimage.io.imread() this line is giving multiple error, i don't know why?

The error I'm getting is :

**FileNotFoundError: No such file: 'F:\Projects\Tensorflow\Code\Training\00032_00000.ppm'**

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the errors; do you mind sharing?

Comment: Thanks man, I've made some changes in the question. Check it out

Comment: The explanation in the error seems very clear. Are you certain that the image file you are trying to load exists?

Comment: yes, 100% sure.

Comment: Instead of `skimage.io.imread(i)`, try `print(os.path.isfile(i))` to debug.